Input for a kotlin scratch file in Android Studio
I want to practice kotlin and save my problems and solutions so that I can revisit them. Also, I need to upload the .kt files to an online course I have taken.
So, I thought of creating scratch files in Android Studio Jellyfish (2023.3.1 |Build #AI-233.14808.21.2331.11709847, built on April 13, 2024)
and uploading them to my GitHub repository.
The very first problem uses the scanner but I could not find a way to provide the input.
The below is the code:
import java.util.Scanner

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Enter the input:")
    val s = Scanner(System.`in`)
    val a = s.nextInt()
    val b = s.nextInt()
    println(a + b)
}

And the below is the UI of the Android Studio where I could not find any prompt to enter the values.

As we can see in the image, the Run window does not show anything to enter as input after I hit the Run button (the green play button on the left side) (ctrl + R).

Please [edit] your question to provide all code as text, not as as screenshot.
